# What does :<> mean in a function declaration?

Tags: syntax, ats

The declaration of `funset_nil` in the file `libats/ML/SATS/funset.sats` reads:

```
fun{} funset_nil{a:t0p} ():<> set(a)
```

What does `:<>` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that the function is pure. No effects shall occur. Please see https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/wiki/effects.